# docker-compose up -d error

Tags: docker, centos, docker-compose

Running `docker-compose up -d`, I got the following error:

> Creating identidock_identidock_1
>
> ERROR: for identidock  Cannot start service identidock: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint identidock_identidock_1 (bd3ab697c9488a5550f8d9598a0edc7202d8fc9335f779a366daf893bffb74c5):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:5000 ! -i docker0: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
>
> (exit status 1))
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

What's the problem?